# PhP Radio button in Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, radio-button

I have a form where you can select a radio button and it should transfer what was selected to the next page. My problem is that no matter which radio button you choose it always transfers the value associated last radio button over instead of the one you chose.

So if I choose Around the World it carries 5 with it instead of 10

I am required to use the GET method.

Here is my code:

```
   $title = array("Around the World"=>"10","Coast to Coast"=>"7","The Big City"=>"5");

    foreach($title as $sub=>$s_value) {
        echo "$sub $$s_value";
        echo '<input type="radio" name="sub" value="', $sub,'">';
        echo "<br>";

    }

 if (empty($_GET["sub"])) {
} else {
    $sub = sub_input($_GET["sub"]);
}

if (empty($_GET["s_value"])) {
} else {
    $s_value = sub_input($_GET["s_value"]);
}

if (isset($title['sub'])){
    $valid=false;
}
```

This is the code for the next page:

```
echo "<b>$sub</b><br />";

echo "Base Total: $ $s_value/mon x $month months <br />";
```

Yes I have omitted a lot of things, because everything else in my code is fine.

I tried doing this as well, adding in an unset() statement but it didnt work. It completely deleted the value variable....

$title = array("Around the World"=>"10","Coast to Coast"=>"7","The Big City"=>"5");

```
    foreach($title as $sub=>$s_value) {
        echo "$sub $$s_value";
        echo '<input type="radio" name="sub" value="', $sub,'">';
        echo "<br>";

    unset($s_value);
    }
```

//I also tried putting the unset here//

```
 if (empty($_GET["sub"])) {
} else {
    $sub = sub_input($_GET["sub"]);
}

if (empty($_GET["s_value"])) {
} else {
    $s_value = sub_input($_GET["s_value"]);
}

if (isset($title['sub'])){
    $valid=false;
}
```

Comment: Im new to PhP, but is that possible while using the foreach loop?

Comment: Your radio buttons within a set should all have the same `name` but different `value`, the problem is with your use of the same variable outside the `foreach`, see my answer below.

Comment: Courtney is correct, I was assuming you had multiple radio button groups.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the names of your variables `$s` & `$s_value` within the foreach loop. The foreach loop is setting these variables and they are then being accessed outside of the foreach loop if either of the GET values is empty such that there is no GET value to replace the contents of the variable. Therefore, it always uses 5 as the value because that is the last `$s_value` that you set.

In summary, changing `$s` & `$s_value` within the foreach loop to something like `$key` & `$value` respectively will fix your problem with the array value. Alternatively, you could unset them after the foreach loop but before the if statements.

Comment: So lets say I omit the if (empty) statments . Im still having the issue.

Comment: You do not omit the if statements. You just need to change the variable names within the foreach.

Comment: Sorry that Im so dense! I finally get why it doesnt work and am in the process of trying to unset them! Here's hoping it works!

Comment: So I tried using unset($s_value); both directly in the loop and out side of it and it completely erased the value, but using unset($sub); gives the desired effect. Still dont have that s_value coming through.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you just happened to switched the values on the loop. `10, 7, 5` are inside the elements, while the names `Around The world... etc` are inside the keys. You just need to switch them. Consider this example:

```
<?php
$title = array("Around the World"=>"10","Coast to Coast"=>"7","The Big City"=>"5");

if(isset($_GET['submit'], $_GET['sub'])) {
    $sub = $_GET['sub'];
    $name = array_search($sub, $title);
    echo '<script>alert("You selected '.$name. ' => '.$sub.'");</script>';
}

?>

<form method="GET" action="index.php">
    <?php foreach($title as $key => $value): ?>
        <input type="radio" name="sub" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /> <?php echo $key; ?> <br/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```